# How to tell Firefox that a file will never change?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to specify some files in Firefox to be remembered forever?

For example, a file like http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js will never change, for sure. But Firefox will lose a few milliseconds every time to make a request, then to receive a 304 response, when there is really no need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cacheability website report](http://www.ircache.net/cgi-bin/cacheability.py?version=1.30&descend=on&query=http%3A//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js) for that URL, the web server is sending good HTTP response headers:

```
Expires: Sat, 23 Jul 2011 03:04:49 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```

So your Firefox should not be checking it with every request.

Comment: Well, probably my explanation was incorrect and I'm sorry for that. The file is cached well, so it is not queried when I switch to another page. But if I refresh a current page, then it is reloaded with a 304 response. Since I'm a web developer, I sometimes refresh the page hundreds of times per hour to check CSS or HTML changes I made, thus requesting jQuery and other files each time.

Comment: Hmmm -- so you are forcing a refresh of the page?  As you found, that negates the cache control headers.  I don't know of a way to make Firefox not to reload that particular file when you force refresh a page.

Comment: you're probably right saying it is impossible. Searched on other websites, and it seems like a refresh does a refresh of everything, every directly linked file.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching to avoid refreshing files when debugging CSS on their own website, a possible solution would be to declare files in JavaScript during debug.

For example, instead of putting an image like `<img src="link-to-a-file" alt="" />`, put just `<img id="ChangeMyId" alt="" />`, then through JavaScript change the `src` property of the image.

Of course, it does not answer my question, since my question is not just about websites I can can change, but about any website.